# What do the hearts around a Pokestop mean?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was walking about and I loaded up Pokemon Go to check if there were any Pokestops in my area. There were two, but one looked different than normal. When I clicked on the Pokestop, there were floating hearts around it.

Are there anything special significance to these hearts?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The hearts floating around a Pokéstop signify that someone has deployed a [lure module](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Lure_Modules) there. Therefore more Pokémon will be attracted there until the lure wears off.

[image: Heart particles signify a regular Lure Model being used.]

There are also glacial, magnetic, and mossy lures which attract water/ice, electric/steel/rock, and bug/grass/poison Pokémon respectively. They can also be used to evolve certain Pokémon into their type specific evolutions. See [here](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2019-05-08-pokemon-go-lures-glacial-mossy-magnetic-lure-modules-explained-6002) for more details.

Comment: Not really important, but I believe they are flower petals and not hearts. :)

Comment: @gitsitgo let's compromise and call them pink thing-a-ma-bobbers

Comment: The different lures will display differently when looking at the map